# Backward pass NFL

Tags: rules, american-football

Why is a not caught Backward pass a fumble and not a incomplete pass? I know all the new rules about a complete pass and why a uncaught pass is incomplete and not a fumble. But I saw a droped backward pass ruled a fumble and not incomplete!

Comment: Are you looking for a quote from the rulebook here, or a historical perspective on the evolution of passing in American football?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest answer is because **a backwards (or lateral) pass isn't considered a forward pass and therefore [can't be ruled incomplete](http://www.nfl.com/rulebook/backwardpass)**. It's often called a "lateral" or "pitch", and it's a way of transferring the ball from one player to another, *not a way of progressing up the field*.

They also differ from forward passes in a few others ways:

- They can be legally attempted from *anywhere on the field*.
- At any time.
- By any player.
- Any number of times.

This leads to them causing [some crazy plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_pass#Famous_plays_in_history) as teams hope to extend plays and score at the end of the game when the clock is up.

Interestingly, [shotgun snaps](http://ftw.usatoday.com/2014/08/zach-bauman-arizona-cardinals-minnesota-Vikings) are also considered a backwards pass.